# Laravel: orWhere en un ciclo

Tags: php, laravel

Al realizar el **foreach**, no me realiza la consulta no que estoy haciendo mal

```
$array = $request->get('array');

$datosql = json_decode(stripslashes($array));

$data = DB::table('materials');
          foreach($datosql as $d){
$data->orWhere('folio', '!=' , $d);
}

$data->orWhere('marca','LIKE', $query.'%');
               $data->orWhere('descripcion','LIKE', $query.'%');
               $data->orWhere('tipo','LIKE', $query.'%');

               $data->orderBy('folio', 'desc');
               $data->get();
```

Comment: `$data->get();` está fuera del foreach. Podrías hacer un `dd($datosql);` y mostrar el resultado?

Comment: De primeras no existe una variable $query, pero necesitaría ver mas datos para ver de donde viene tu error